# NoMethodError raised following Railscast #250

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following the 'Authentication from scratch' railscast but cannot get it to work.

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(params[:user])
        if @user.save
            redirect_to products_path, notice: 'User created successfully'
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
end
```

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  validates_uniqueness_of :email
end
```

users#new form:

```
<h1>Sign up form</h1>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>

    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>

    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

    <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

When I try to go to the new user form it throws up a NoMethodError - undefined method 'email' referring to the line that has 'f.text_field :email'.

What am I missing here?

Thanks any help appreciated.

Comment: have u run the migration for creating users tables with mentioned columns.

Comment: Is there a field "email" in users table?

Comment: You are right @techvineet. In the tutorial Ryan ran this command: `$ rails g resource user email password_digest`. This gave him columns in the table called `email` and `password_digest`. But when I ran that command it only gave me a column called `password_digest`. I will need to add a new column to the user table called `email`.

Comment: your users table does not have email field/column Please run the migration first to create a users table with email column......

Comment: @user2623004 This sounds weird. It should create email field automatically in table but in case it has not you can create your own migration and add it.

Comment: Oops, I meant when I ran the command it gave me a column called `email_digest`. Not sure why it worked for him and not me. Oh well, I made a migration to delete that column and added the `email` and `password_digest` columns myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `users` table does not have an `email` column. Please run a migration to add the column to your `users` table.